# When does an array variable represent the entire array, and when the element indexed by `0`?

Tags: bash, variable, array

Bash manual says:

> Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing with a subscript of 0.

In Bash or POSIX shell, is there some general rule for when an array variable represents the entire array, and when it represents the element indexed by `0`?

For example,

1. It seems that after `declare` an array variable means the entire
   array, while  in parameter expansion, it means the element indexed
   by `0`:

   ```
   $ declare -p x
   declare -a x='([1]="b" [2]="c")'
   $ echo $x
   ```
2. In `[[ -v myarr ]]`, does `myarr` mean the array or `myarr[0]`?

Comment: POSIX shells don't have arrays.

Answer (score 3):

I think your confusion is on the word **"referencing."**

You're not *referencing* the array variable after `declare` at all; you're only giving the name `x`.

To reference a variable you have to put a `$` before the name.

Try searching through the bash man page for all instances of `referenc` and read them.

---

As for the second question:

> In `[[ -v myarr ]]`, does `myarr` mean the array or `myarr[0]`?

By test, it means `myarr[0]`.

```
$ declare -p myarr
bash: declare: myarr: not found
$ myarr=()
$ declare -p myarr
declare -a myarr='()'
$ echo $myarr

$ [[ -v myarr ]] && echo is set
$ [[ -v myarr[0] ]] && echo is set
$ [[ -v myarr[1] ]] && echo is set
$ myarr+=([1]=b)
$ declare -p myarr
declare -a myarr='([1]="b")'
$ echo $myarr

$ [[ -v myarr ]] && echo is set
$ [[ -v myarr[0] ]] && echo is set
$ [[ -v myarr[1] ]] && echo is set
is set
$ myarr+=([0]=q)
$ declare -p myarr
declare -a myarr='([0]="q" [1]="b")'
$ echo $myarr
q
$ [[ -v myarr ]] && echo is set
is set
$ [[ -v myarr[0] ]] && echo is set
is set
$ [[ -v myarr[1] ]] && echo is set
is set
$
```

Comment: thanks. In `[[ -v myarr ]]`, does `myarr` mean the array or `myarr[0]`?

Comment: @Tim, there's no such test as `-v` that I can find.  It throws a syntax error on my version of `bash`.

Comment: add a space before `]]`

Comment: @Tim, your last comment makes no sense.  `-v` is not a primary for bash conditional expressions.  See `LESS=+/^CONDITIONAL\ EXPRESSIONS man bash`.

Comment: I am not sure why you believe that my comment makes no sense. I read the bash manual. Search for "True if the shell variable varname is set (has been assigned a value)."

Comment: @Tim, `[[ -v myarr ]]` doesn't mean anything—it is a syntax error because it is not a valid conditional expression.  Its parts therefore don't mean anything either.  There has to be an intended *correct* statement for these parts to mean something.  What is the syntactically correct statement you were thinking of?  (I am using `bash` 4.3.30 and 4.1.2; are you using a later version with more options?)

Comment: @Wildcard, see [§6.4 Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions); it was introduced in 4.2.

Comment: @MichaelHomer, thanks, that's what I was missing.  I see now that my 4.3.30 bash shell does in fact support this, but I have an outdated man page on that box.

Comment: @Tim, sorry for the misunderstanding.  I've updated my answer now to include the `[[ -v myarr ]]` part.

Comment: So In `[[ -v myarr ]]`, `myarr` means  `myarr[0]`, without `$` in front of `myarr`?

Comment: @Tim, evidently so.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, it works on my system with bash 4.3.30.  I just tried the code from your comment and got the output `is set`.

Comment: @Wildcard And yes, you are correct, Sir. I tested in the wrong version of bash. It works in bash 4.3 and 4.4. However, in versions 4.3 and 4.4, the correct test for the whole array is `[[ -v myarr[@] ]]`. Please try `unset myarr; myarr[88]=''; [[ -v myarr[@] ]] && echo "is set"` (also work with Associative arrays). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing variables with strings that represent "variable names".

A `$variable` is the variable, `variable` is just an string that is interpreted as a variable by some commands.

Try this:

```
$ a=x
$ x=(111 222 333)
$ declare -p $a
declare -a x='([0]="111" [1]="222" [2]="333")'
```

The expansion of variable a (`$a`) gave string `x`, which was interpreted by declare as a "variable-name" and then expanded and printed.

In `[[ -v myarr ]]` also the test is interpreting the string `myarr` as a variable, therefore it is always the whole variable.

Try

```
$ a=myarr
$ unset myarr
$ [[ -v $a ]] && echo set || echo unset
unset

$ myarr[5]=five
$ [[ -v $a ]] && echo set || echo unset
set
```